# GIven two binary numbers, copy a subset from one to another

Tags: c++, c, binary, bit-manipulation

Let's say I have two binary numbers `00110010` and `11101110`, and I would like to copy the last 4 values from second to the first to form a binary number of `00111110`. Is there clean way to do this using bitwise operations on two bytes (or larger datatypes). Assume binary packed datatypes.

Also, is there a generic solution to this problem where *any* subset can be copied over. Let's say I wanted to copy some middle 3 bits from one number to another, what's the best way to accomplish this?

Comment: By "copy over" do you mean replace?

Comment: @mbratch Yes, feel free to edit.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you have inputs `x` and `y` and want to copy a certain set of bits from `x` to `y`, say, the bits that are `1`s in some variable `m` (a *mask* for the bits you want to copy), this can be done as follows:

```
int copy(int x, int y, int m) {
    return ((x & m) | (y & (~m)));
}
```

This will also work on things larger or smaller than `int`s, such as `char`s, `short`s, `long`s, etc.

Taking `(x & m)` will give only the bits in `x` for which `m` has a `1` at that position, and
`(y & (~m))` will give only the bits in `y` for which `m` does not have a `1` at that position.

These are then ORed together with `|` to give the value whose bits in the positions where `m` has a `1` come from `x`, and whose bits in the positions where `m` has a `0` come from `y`.

Your particular case would have `x = 0xee`, `y = 0x32`, and `m = 0xF`.

Comment: The variable `m` is known as a `mask`.

Comment: What would be the case where you wanted to copy a subset to a different location within the other binary number. Would you just have the same method but with two different masks?

Comment: This depends greatly on which locations you're using. If both locations have the same bit pattern, just shifted around, then it can be done much like this, but with an additional bitshift. However, if your patterns differ, like 0011 and 0101, it gets much more complicated.

Answer (score 1):

you can try this

```
#include "stdio.h"

    int main()
    {
            int a = 0x52;
            int b = 0xee;

            int c = (a&0xF0)|(b&0x0F);


            printf(" %x %d\n",  c, c);

    }
```

a is `00110010`, b is `11101110`